# How to perform incremental load using AWS EMR (Pyspark) the right way?

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have all my data available in S3 location `s3://sample/input_data`

I do my ETL by deploying AWS EMR and using PySpark.

PySpark script is very simple.

- I load `s3://sample/input_data` as spark dataframe.
- Partition it by one column.
- Save the dataframe as Parquet file with write option in 'append' mode into S3 location `s3://sample/output_data`
- Then copy all files in `s3://sample/input_data` to `s3://sample/archive_data` and delete all data in `s3://sample/input_data`

So when a new data comes in `s3://sample/input_data`, it only process the new file and save it in `s3://sample/output_data` with partition.

Is there any inbuilt latch AWS EMR provides that I should be aware of which I can use it instead of doing the last step of my PySpark script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use [Delta Lake](https://datapipelineguy.medium.com/delta-lake-on-aws-emr-part-1-896aa3896cbb) for those purposes or partition your input directory by a time interval like `s3://sample/input_data/year=2021/month=11/day=11/` so that you only process data from that time interval.

Answer (score 0):

You can use step function in EMR.
The jar would be script-runner.jar
s3://.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar where  is the Region in which your Amazon EMR cluster resides. You can use script-runner.jar to run scripts saved locally or on Amazon S3 on your cluster

You must specify shell script to  run. In you case cp command